# NativeScript dynamic array - elements dropping off screen at bottom?

Tags: ios, vue.js, mobile, nativescript

I have an annoying issue with NativeScript styled with Vue.

I have a dynamic array, which allows user input entered in via a modal. Code snippet below:

```
<StackLayout v-show="model.length > 0" class="mt-4">
        <Label class="Form-label ml-4 mr-4">Actions</Label>
        <GridLayout class="Collection-item"
                    columns="*,auto" rows="auto, auto, auto, *"
                    v-for="(action, actionIndex) in model"
                    :key="actionIndex"
        >
            <Label
                    row="0"
                    col="0"
                    class="Collection-item-action"
                    textWrap="true"
                    v-on:tap="actionEdit(actionIndex)"
            >
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Action Assigned To: " fontWeight="bold" />
                    <Span v-if="action.assignee.person !== null" :text="action.assignee.person.firstName + ' ' + action.assignee.person.lastName" />
                    <Span v-else text="N/A" />
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
            <Label
                    row="1"
                    col="0"
                    class="Collection-item-action"
                    v-on:tap="actionEdit(actionIndex)"
            >
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Action Before: " fontWeight="bold" />
                    <Span :text="formatDateString(action.actionBefore, 'dd/MM/yyyy')" />
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
            <Label
                    row="2"
                    col="0"
                    class="Collection-item-action"
                    fontWeight="bold"
                    v-on:tap="actionEdit(actionIndex)"
            >Description:</Label>
            <Label
                    row="3"
                    col="0"
                    textWrap="true"
                    class="Collection-item-action"
                    :text="action.description"
                    v-on:tap="actionEdit(actionIndex)"
            />
            <Button
                    v-show="editable"
                    row="0"
                    col="1"
                    rowSpan="3"
                    class="fa Dismiss"
                    v-on:tap="actionRemove(actionIndex)"
                    :text.decode="`\uf056`"
            />
        </GridLayout>
        <StackLayout class="ml-4 mr-4 mb-4">
            <Button class="Collection-addItem"
                    text="Add Action"
                    v-on:tap="actionAdd"
            />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

The code to add input via modal:

```
this.$showModal(AddActionModal).then(data => {
                    if (!data) {
                        return
                    }

                    let newAction = ActionModel.create()

                    newAction.description = data.description
                    newAction.actionBefore = data.actionBefore
                    newAction.assignee = data.assignee

                    this.model.push(newAction)

                    this.$emit('update', this.model)
                })
```

And modal code:

```
onSubmit () {
        this.$v.$touch()
        if (!this.$v.$error) {
            this.$modal.close({
                description: this.model.description,
                actionBefore: this.model.actionBefore,
                assignee: this.model.assignee
            })
        }
    },
```

When the modal closes, the item is added to the screen, but the button that sits below it is now out of scrollable view. See screenshot:
[After item is added, Continue button is now outside of scrollable view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfNyo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, when I change the bbackground of the scrollview, it appears when an element is added to this array it actually randomly pads the top element in the scrollview.. see screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG2wi.png)